On Prime, Lcm and Divisibility

Let $d_n= \text{lcm} \{1,2,3..., n \}$ then prove that for any prime $p$ $$ \left(\frac{1}{p^5-1}\right)\left(\frac{d_{p}}{p}\right)^5  \text{is not an integer}$$

Clearly $$\frac{d_p}{p}\in\mathbb{Z},\ \ \text{so}\ \ \  \left(\frac{d_p}{p}\right)^5\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Now if $$\left(\frac{1}{p^5-1}\right)\left(\frac{d_{p}}{p}\right)^5=r\in\mathbb{Z}$$ then
$$\left(\frac{d_{p}}{p}\right)^5=r(p^5-1)$$ On factoring we have $$\left(\frac{d_{p}}{p}\right)^5=r(p-1)(p^4+p^3+p^2+p+1)$$ Hence $$(p^4+p^3+p^2+p+1)\ \ \text{divides}\ \ \left(\frac{d_{p}}{p}\right)^5$$
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

@RossMillikan I do not understand: there is no $n$ in the claim made by OP, only in the definition.

@hello_123:  I missed that it was $d_p$ in the equation

@RossMillikan Thanks for the comment. Please help me with the problem

See also OP's similar recent question. $\ \ $

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but isn't it true that $\tfrac{d_p}{p}=d_{p-1}$?

Also, what makes you believe this is true?

As a final comment, this seems (nearly?) equivalent to showing that $p^4+p^3+p^2+p+1$ has a prime factor $q>p$. Not sure if a few messy details work out well, but it would definitely be sufficient to prove the claim.

@Servaes having experimented with that yesterday, I found a counter example for a non-prime $p$ but for primes I haven't found any. Seems difficult to prove.

If curious, the counter example was $p=2205$. It was found by user Peter in a chatroom.

The claim is false as seen with counter-examples $p \in \{7307, 9769\}$.
Massive thanks to user @Peter who helped in this answer via the use of CAS and other softwares to evaluate large prime numbers and their prime factors which proved invariably helpful in providing a counterexample to the OP's claim.

First off, one can write $d_p = \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots, p) = \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3, \dots, p-1),p) = \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,p-1)\cdot p = d_{p-1}p$ for prime $p$. Then the problem reduces to showing that $$\frac{d_{p-1}^5}{p^5-1}\notin \mathbb Z$$
Notice that the numerator is divisible by all prime numbers $<p$. So if one finds such a $p$ that $p^5 - 1$ has a prime factor $k\geq p$ then it is a sufficient condition to show that the expression isn't an integer. This seems to be true for many primes $p$.
On the contrary, we looked at primes $p$ s.t. $p^5 - 1$'s greatest prime factor was $<p$. With a computer search, such primes $p < 10^4$ came out to be $7307$ and $9769$. Then for these $p$ if each prime factor in the denominator had a multiplicity lower than that in the numerator, such a $p$ would be a valid counterexample to the claim. On checking the prime factorisation of $7307^5 - 1$ one realises all prime factors have multiplicity $1$ while on checking the prime factorisation of $9769^5 - 1$ one finds all its prime factors have multiplicity $\le 3$, whereas each prime factor in the numerator has multiplicity at least $5$. This implies $p \in \{7307, 9769\}$ do not follow the OP's claim.

The following computer code was attached by Peter to find such primes.
gp > forprime(s=1,10^4,n=s^5-1;w=component(factor(n),1)~;if(vecmax(w)<s,print(s)))
7307
9769
gp >


That is a nice code to find counter-examples. It is much faster than the brute force attack: forprime(p=2,10^4,if((lcm(vector(p,x,x))/p)^5%(p^5-1)==0,print(p)))
